# How are the two humans selected to repopulate the world after Ragnarök?

Tags: norse, ragnarok

According to Norse Mythology, Ragnarök is a series of future events that means great disasters for the world and the end of many important and powerful gods:

> In Norse mythology, Ragnarök is a series of future events, including a great battle foretold to ultimately result in the death of a number of major figures (including the gods Odin, Thor, Týr, Freyr, Heimdallr, and Loki), the occurrence of various natural disasters, and the subsequent submersion of the world in water. Afterward, the world will resurface anew and fertile, the surviving and returning gods will meet, and the world will be repopulated by two human survivors . Ragnarök is an important event in the Norse canon, and has been the subject of scholarly discourse and theory.
>
> <sub>source: Wikipedia article on [Ragnarök](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragnar%C3%B6k)</sub>

After Ragnarök, it is said that the world will be repopulated with two human survivors. How will these two human survivors be chosen? Will they be randomly chosen or selected by the remaining gods who didn't die during Ragnarök?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The two human survivors are [Lif and Lifthrasir](http://norse-mythology.org/lif-lifthrasir/). They live through Ragnarök by [hiding in Yggdrasil](http://www.viking-mythology.com/ragnarok.php) before the great battles, supposedly [in Hoddmimir's wood](http://www.timelessmyths.com/norse/ragnarok.html#NewAge). Apparently, [Vafthrudnir told this to Odin](http://www.godchecker.com/pantheon/norse-mythology.php?deity=RAGNAROK) in a prophecy.

They are mentioned in verse 45 of [*Vafþrúðnismál*](http://www.heimskringla.no/wiki/Vaf%C3%BEr%C3%BA%C3%B0nism%C3%A1l):

> "Líf ok Lifþrasir,
>   
> en þau leynask munu
>   
> í holti Hoddmímis;
>   
> morgindöggvar
>   
> þau sér at mat hafa,
>   en þaðan af aldir alask."

I don't know Icelandic, but [this answer](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/131/how-is-the-hoddm%c3%admis-holt-able-to-protect-humans-from-ragnar%c3%b6k/271#271) gives me

> 45. Lif and Lifthrasir
>       lie hidden
>       in the grove of Hoard-Mimir;
>       the morning dews
>       they shall have as meat,
>       from them generations will spring.

<sub>source: http://www.germanicmythology.com/PoeticEdda/GRM27.html</sub>

This verse is the source of the prophecy to Odin.

It seems that the two humans were, though prophesied, simply random people who happened to find a safe (and sacred) place to hide.

For the reasons why Yggdrasil was safe, see [How is the Hoddmímis holt able to protect humans from Ragnarök?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/131/how-is-the-hoddm%c3%admis-holt-able-to-protect-humans-from-ragnar%c3%b6k?lq=1)